# ssh login permission denied from a specific machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I try to login a server via ssh from 3 machines, A, B and C. A is from my home, B and C are from school network. I can login the ssh server from A and B, but not from C. On host C, I get this:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'mynet.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myname/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ssh_userA@mynet.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_userA@mynet.com's password:
```

I have done following on the ssh server.

I have changed /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny to another temp name and did /etc/init.d/ssh reload

I have done iptables -F to clean up all firewall rules, and did iptables -L to verify it's all open.

I am sure the pasword for ssh_userA is correct since I can use it to login from A and B. I also tried to add a new user ssh_userB. The problem still, only host C gives me a permission denied problem. However, from host C I can successfully login to another ssh server.

Host A and C are debian, B is centOS.

Answer (score 0):

wild guess. perhaps use internal IP when you are in the same network?

Answer (score 0):

check AllowUsers directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (Centos), this can setup user@ip level for SSH accesses.